# React How To: server side debugging?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, webpack, serverside-javascript

I've got following configuration:

- react
- redux
- webpack2
- express (+webpack-dev-middleware)

What are the best practices for debugging **server side** execution of the application?

Answer (score 0):

One of easy ways to solve this problem - to organize assembly of server code in precisely the same way, as well as client. It solves also a set of other problems, including convenient debugging, testing and even some questions of internationalization at the same time.

On this subject there are a magnificent report and the presentation: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1WhnbcsUOqZbycHGLW9zd30m2BxCzaejrQH8Kx6mcIes/edit#slide=id.g1373bc98c9_0_215

As it is realized words, and in practice - you can look in this repository: https://github.com/MrCheater/phoebe-spa/tree/dev

Comment: thanks for the links, but honestly I don't see explicit answer to my question in it.